# usleep() causing everything to "sleep"

Tags: php

I have two php scripts and when I call one that has a loop with usleep() in it, it delays the execution of complete other script?

Any ideas why this would be?

Thanks!

Comment: How do you know this? - How are these two scripts related to each other, if at all?

Comment: So, simplified version.  I have one page that is polling a php page (Page A) via ajax every second.  I have another page that is/will be run via cron to make updates every second.  When I am on the page that is polling, then run the script that has the usleep() the ajax calls to the other php page, virtually stop, they go from taking a few milliseconds to many seconds.  When the page with usleep() stops running, it goes back to a few milliseconds.  I tried having the cron page ONLY have the usleep(), no additional code - and it still stalls the requests.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `session_write_close()` otherwise it stops all php in that session from running.

Comment: Thank you for that answer! I have been stuck on this issue for 12 hours!

Answer (score 2):

Is the usleep on the server? If yes, do you have sessions enabled? That might be whats blocking your scripts. When the first script opens up the session the other with the same session identifier cannot continue untill the first one closes it. That would explain why the second script resumes instantly after the first one dies

Answer (score 0):

Try using two browsers. Or if you are using Chrome, try opening an Incognito instance to verify this. In your first script that has usleep(), your browser waits for a response. While your browser is waiting for this response, it puts your other request on hold so basically your other request hasn't reached the server yet.

So what you can do is open another browser (or the incognito window), and try loading the second script.

Both should load without waiting for each other.